# Mongoid validations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Mongoid model, and the validations aren't working, at all. No error messages, no problems, but I can insert invalid data.

```
class Place
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :address, :type => String, :required => true
  field :headline, :type => String, :required => true
  validates :headline, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 10, :allow_blank => false }
  validates :address, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 5, :allow_blank => false }
  # ...
end
```

Even though it looks like it's supposed to work, the model saves without throwing an error (value nil or "abc", for example).

How do I get them to work?

Answer (score 3):

For me your validations are working correctly:

```
place = Place.create(:headline => nil, :address => nil)
puts place.persisted?  # false
puts place.valid?      # false
puts place.save        # false
```

The `create` and `save` methods do not raise an exception, `save` returns false if  unsuccessful (fails validation). The `save!` method does raise the following exception:

```
Validation failed - Headline can't be blank, Headline is too short (minimum is 10 characters), Address can't be blank, Address is too short (minimum is 5 characters). (Mongoid::Errors::Validations)
```

Comment: For me it doesn't work. Any idea why this might be: irb(main):002:0> a.persisted?
=> true
irb(main):003:0> a.valid?
=> true
irb(main):004:0> a.save!
=> true
irb(main):005:0> a.save
=> true
irb(main):006:0> a.destroy
=> true

Comment: Thats strange, I can't think of a reason for that. I am using mongoid 2.0.2 and active-model 3.0.9. Is it possible that validations are switched off somehow? I know that you can override validations with save(false) but I don't know of any application wide switch.

Comment: I can't either, and it's driving me crazy ;-)